# How to configure Windows (7/8/10) to use a proxy with authentication

Tags: authentication, proxy

I need to use certain software that connects with a server, that allows connections only from whitelisted IPS. To solve this, I have a droplet with fixed IP on DigitalOcean where I use Squid3 as proxy. I configure my system to work through the proxy, and I tell the central server to whitelist that proxy server IP.

Up to here all is great, but as I should have guessed, some people are using my proxy to send malicious packages, and now the server provider is telling me to get it sorted out, or they will cancel my account.

I added authentication to the proxy, and the attacks have stopped, since the attackers do not know the user/pass combination.

But now the problem I have is that I don't see any way to configure Windows to use authentication when connecting to the proxy! I am not talking just about HTTP requests, since the browsers allow for authentication. I am talking about some custom software that needs to communicate as well with this central server.

Is there any way to configure Windows so that it connects to the proxy passing the necessary username and password?

Comment: Can you share which other specific protocols other than http need to be addressed?

Comment: I do not know what protocol they use. They have a "SDK Manager" that connects to the server to download libraries.

Comment: I'm thinking .pac files, but not totally sure on the id + pw part. I would guess the download is using one of the usual: https, ftp, ftps....  all can be set up with a .pac file to auto configure the OS internet connection settings but my knowledge ends with that general notion.

Comment: Im not familiar with .pac files, but if it cant handle authentication, it is pointless...

Comment: Check out this conversation: http://serverfault.com/questions/394130/how-to-automatically-configure-username-password-with-proxy-pac-file  Maybe proxy rules are a better answer than id / pw.

Comment: What kind of rules where you thinking? I'm not in a corporation. I connect from my home. So it's hard to guess what my ip will be..

Comment: Ouch. That was the kind of rule I was thinking of.  A static IP will cost more, no doubt, than a home connection.  I wonder if some sort of dynamic DNS service could be used to keep your rules updated to match your assigned IP address - but to be clear, I'm guessing beyond this point.